# Open new C project with eclipse for new developer

Tags: c, eclipse, include

I want to start learning C and download `Eclipse` for C\C++ and want to start new project.
I found [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcdt_c_build_over.htm) tutorial and after create new project, choose C project with `MinGcc` and hit finish this is the errors i got:

> Symbol 'EXIT_SUCCESS' could not be resolved

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: please do not redirect to third-party urls.

Comment: i cannot upload image from my machine until reputation of 10

Comment: atleast you can write down the error message and error code, right?

Comment: OK that's fine, updated

Answer (score 2):

EXIT_SUCCESS is defined in stdlib.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Based on your comments, your problem appears to be with Eclipse. You might want to try off the main menu: 
Project->C/C++ Index->

- Freshen All Files
- Update with Modified Files
- **Re-resolve Unresolved Includes**
- **Search for Unresolved Includes**

In the Project Exlorer tree, it lists where Eclipse CDT looks for include files. You should see a directory in there that holds stdlib.h. On my machine it is in c:\MinGW\include.

[image]

Comment: I have this red lines under #include <stdio.h>, #include<stdlib.h> and return EXIT_SUCCESS, what i need to change ?

Comment: What does it say when you hover the cursor over one of those red lines? I suspect it can't find those files. I don't use Eclipse so don't know what the setup should be to find them. I assume that the error is coming from gcc and not Eclipse -  you are able to invoke gcc, that is, do a compile?

Comment: I would add an "Eclipse" tag to your question as it is an Eclipse setup issue.

Comment: @motrer To test that your MinGW compiler is setup correctly you could go to the Windows cmd prompt and type c:\path\to\gcc c:\path\to\your_program.c and see if that compiles.

Comment: @motrer If you still have a problem I added the menu options that may help above.